# Multiple upload files with flex 3 and Web dynpro java

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, webdynpro

I'm trying to do multi upload files with flex 3 and web dynpro java.

I have the flex part: http://weblog.cahlan.com/files/file_uploads/srcview/index.html

Here life demo: http://weblog.cahlan.com/files/FileUpload/FileUploadApp.html

But I need to upload files from web dynpro java with the files path or upload from flex and send them to webdyn pro.

Can I do it? I'm looking for example or tutorial but I don't find nothing!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I find a solution here: https://sites.google.com/site/vivekgoenka/web-dynpro-java/sample-codes-01